# Calculated value in Groovy enum

Tags: java, groovy, enums

I need to create an enum or a class that has some predefined values and must have an option to calculate other values. Say we have this enum:

```
enum Duration {

    ONE_HOUR("1${DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR}"),
    ONE_DAY("24${DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR}"),
    ONE_WEEK("7${DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY}"),
    ONE_MONTH("30${DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY}")

    String duration

    Environment(String duration) {
        this.duration = duration
    }

    static String custom(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
        // TODO Calculate difference in days between the two dates  
    }

    private static class DurationUnits {
        public static final String DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR = "h"
        public static final String DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY = "d"
    }

}
```

So my question is if I can define an enum value, say `CUSTOM`, that represents the value of all the non predefined ones. That is, a generic value for the `custom(Date a, Date b)` method.
I can't figure out how to do it, actually I don't think it's even possible.

As an alternative I'm thinking of creating a class instead of an enum, like this:

```
class Duration {

    private static final String DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR = "h"
    private static final String DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY = "d"

    /** Predefined values */

    static final String ONE_HOUR = "1${DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR}"
    static final String ONE_DAY = "24${DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR}"
    static final String ONE_WEEK = "7${DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY}"
    static final String ONE_MONTH = "30${DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY}"

    static String custom(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        // TODO Calculate difference in days between the two dates
    }

}
```

What do you think is the best way to go? This duration will be an input parameter to a method that calls a REST web service, that's why I was trying to define it as an enum instead of just passing a string.

Comment: Not sure if your example with dates is just an illustrative example or actually what you want to achieve. If so, consider using time categories : http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html, it certainly can help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use String append.

```
ONE_HOUR("1" + DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR),
ONE_DAY("24" + DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR),
ONE_WEEK("7" + DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY),
ONE_MONTH("30" + DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_DAY);
```

However it might be better to use TimeUnits

```
ONE_HOUR(1, TimeUnit.HOUR),
ONE_DAY(1, TimeUnit.DAY),
ONE_WEEK(7, TimeUnit.DAY),
ONE_MONTH(30, TimeUnit.DAY);
```

Note: not all months have 30 days.

You can also use [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) for a duration of time.

```
Duration ONE_HOUR = Duration.ofHours(1);
Duration ONE_DAY = Duration.ofDays(1);
```

This would allow you to create more Duration as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it were Java (I'm not a Groovy expert) I'd suggest something like `ONE_HOUR("1" + DurationUnits.DURATION_SUFFIX_HOUR),` or yet better use another enum that represents the unit itself, e.g. like this:

```
enum DurationUnit {
   HOUR ("k"),
   DAY( "d" );

   private final String key; 

   //constructor and getter
}

enum Duration {
  ONE_HOUR(1, DurationUnit.HOUR ),
  ...

  private final int quantity;
  private DurationUnit unit;

  //constructor and getters

  public String toString() {        
    return quantity + unit.getKey(); //should return 1h, 24h, 1d etc.
  }
}
```

This should be doable in Groovy as well and would allow for calculations/comparisons without needing to parse a string.

**Update:**

For custom durations (and if Java 8's own `Duration` class doesn't fit your needs) you'd make `Duration` a normal (immutable) class with some constants:

```
class Duration {
  public static final Duration ONE_HOUR = new Duration(1, DurationUnit.HOUR );
  ...

  private final int quantity;
  private DurationUnit unit;

  //constructor and getters
}
```

Comment: And how could I represent a custom duration? Let's say, for example, I need a 15 days value (15 is dynamic, it could be 3, 8, or 200)... is there a way to do this with enum?

Comment: @sanzoan in that case I'd probably not use an enum for `Duration` but a custom class along with some constants for the common values (basically an enum is implemented that way anyways). Java 8's own `Duration` class would be an example of that (having the constant `ZERO`).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I also think that would be the best solution.